# two plots are linked by an unwanted line - animated line

Tags: matlab, animation, plot

I am using animatedline to create an animation of a camshaft rotating and moving the bucket which sits on the valve. 
I have created what i thought were two separate plots, one of the polar coordinates of the valve lift profile, and a horizontal line which is based on the minimum value of the camshaft in the Y direction. However, I have plotted these two and the animation works well apart from there being a line which connects the last point of the cam lobe to the horizontal line and I'm trying to get rid of it.
Below is a picture explaining what i mean;

[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGEL5.jpg)

i have attached the .mat file of the cam lift profile, and my code is below. I'm sure I am missing something obvious but I might be too close to the woods to see the trees.

Raw_Cam_Data file is attached by dropbox in below link (i think this will work?)

[Raw_Cam_Data.mat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vs3a892r9ikuarx/Raw_Cam_Data.mat?dl=0)

```
clear
clc
load('Raw_Cam_Data')
theta = deg2rad(1:1:360)
phi = theta'
R = Lift' + 17.6
%==============================
h = animatedline;
axis([-30 30 -30 30])
rotation = (-pi:pi/180:pi - (pi/180))'
output = zeros(360,1)
for II = 1:1:length(phi)-1

    x = R .* sin(theta + rotation(II))
    y = R .* cos(theta + rotation(II))

    [bucket, indice] = (min(y))
    output(II) = indice
    x_bucket = linspace(-25,25,359)
    y_bucket = bucket * ones(359,1)

    addpoints(h, x, y)
    addpoints(h, x_bucket, y_bucket)
    drawnow
    clearpoints(h)

end
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post complete code, that can be run as is. That is, replaced the `load` line by a toy example

Comment: toy example will be difficult to write in code as it is measured data, i have attached a dropbox link with the original data i am using. please let me know if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer on this thread on the MATLAB forum

[MATLAB Forum Post](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/301358-how-do-i-do-multi-animated-lines-in-one-axes)

The part i missed was i was plotting both the datasets on one graph without 'hold on' and then creating two separate graphs/ animations.

This is intuitive but i stupidly missed it. Code for a working example is below along with the .mat file

[Raw_Cam_Data.mat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vs3a892r9ikuarx/Raw_Cam_Data.mat?dl=0)

```
clear
clc
load('Raw_Cam_Data')

theta = deg2rad(1:1:360)
phi = theta'
R = Lift' + 17.6
%==============================

figure      % create new figure
hold on     % hold on to plot all data on the same figure
h = animatedline;   %animation 1, AKA first plot
h2 = animatedline   %animation 2, AKA second plot

axis([-30 30 -30 30])
rotation = (-pi:pi/180:pi - (pi/180))'
output = zeros(360,1)
for II = 1:1:length(phi)-1

    x = R .* sin(theta + rotation(II))
    y = R .* cos(theta + rotation(II))

    [bucket, indice] = (min(y))
    output(II) = indice
    x_bucket = linspace(-25,25,360)
    y_bucket = bucket * ones(360,1)

    addpoints(h, x, y)      %add points from first plot/ animation
    addpoints(h2, x_bucket, y_bucket)   %add points from second plot/ animation
    drawnow
    clearpoints(h)          % clear points from first plot
    clearpoints(h2)         % clear points from second plot

end
```